# What is the original variant of the "Charles V Dominating Fury" statue?

Tags: art

The statue "Charles V Dominating Fury" by Leone Leoni is known in two variants, in one the emperor is naked, in the other he is armoured. I wonder which variant is the original?

[image: Carlos V and the Fury]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the same statue, the armour is removable.

The statue is today kept at the [Museo Nacional Del Prado](http://www.museodelprado.es/en/the-collection/online-gallery/on-line-gallery/obra/charles-v-and-the-fury/?no_cache=1):

> The Emperor stands over a nude figure representing Fury, which takes the form of a mature man in chains with an angry and hateful expression. Fury holds a lit torch in his right hand. The group rests on a base covered with arms and military trophies, crafted with a goldsmith’s attention to detail: a trident, a trompet, a mace, a quiver and even a lictor’s fasces with its hatchet, emphasize this group’s similarity to a work from Antiquity.
>
> This idea is related to the Renassance mentality, which associated imperial power with the Roman past in both a political and an esthetic sense. In keeping with this tendency, the artists represent the emperor nude here, as in an ancient sculpture. To this, they added the armor, which can still be removed today.

Comment: Removable armour… http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDYwMA==/z/H~AAAOSwxH1UAVS0/$_35.JPG